# Freighter Travel for Vegetarians

Tags: food-and-drink, freighter-travel

Is it possible to get vegetarian food on freighters?

We are interested in discovering which, if any, dietary restrictions might be accommodated during freighter travel.
These are the freighters which can be booked through the specialized websites.

Comment: Can you try to narrow down your question ? Which kind of freighter, from where to where, which company ?

Comment: Freighters that market to tourists, such as the Aranui in French Polynesia, often have broader dining options. Freighters that take passengers simply for extra income tend to cook primarily for the crew's needs.

Comment: The different Aranui, Marion Dufresne, RMS St Helena or Hurtigruten ships are really passenger ships. They accommodate 100-200 passengers and even if they have additional purposes, they are regulated and staffed as passenger ships. The only exception I am aware of would be the [MV Silver Supporter](https://www.visitpitcairn.pn/mv-silver-supporter). The accommodation looks really nice, there is a buffet and dietary restrictions are mentioned but the number of passengers is limited to 12, which is the threshold for a passenger vessel under the SOLAS convention.

Answer (score 8):

You should not expect to choose from a menu or have anything like a restaurant experience, you're simply sharing meals with the crew. In general, everybody's priority is keeping the ship on the move. The officers will be informed in advance that they have a passenger and perhaps your basic info (name, age, citizenship) but other than that, taking care of you is not their job. For example, when and where you board the ship is organized with the local agent from the shipping line, nobody on board is worrying about that.

So it would not seem reasonable to have a separate meal cooked for you. And, in my experience, the food isn't generally vegetarian, far from it. There is also no system in place to communicate special requirements in advance like there might be for air transport.

That said, on my last trip, the cook was very nice and always asked if I liked what he had planned. Since I always said yes, I don't know how much he would have been able to accommodate special requirements but it was always possible to have only salad or (non-vegetarian) soup if you didn't feel like a full meal. Fruit, snacks, or ice cream were also always available (although here as well the snacks included mostly cold meats).

Comment: Although I am a vegan who likes to travel the hard way, I have to up vote this since that is how the world is.  Being vegetarian or vegan is now easy in some places.  I remember when it wasn't easy anywhere and it still isn't when you go off the beaten track.

Comment: Note too that meal options will largely depend on the culture of the crew, or even just the cook (if there even is a dedicated cook and cooking isn't a shared responsibility between the other crew members), modified to what supplies are available at a budget at the last port of call.

Comment: Even with airlines it's hit and miss when you preorder a special meal. I'm a diabetic and more often than not the diabetic meal is so loaded with carbs and even includes the sugar loaded cakes and cookies that come with the regular meals it's effectively inedible for me.